# Magento 1.9.1 Cron Jobs

Tags: sales-order, cron, ce-1.9.1.0

Is it possible not to use the cron jobs to send my sales confirmation email? I am on a shared hosting with hostgator and they don't allow cron jobs to be less than every 15 minutes. I don't want my customer to see an order confirmation after 10 or 15 minutes. IS there a way to change this?

Comment: I see no reason on why they should put such archaic limit in place. One better way is to consider another provider who allows you to set a shorter interval for your Cron Jobs.

Comment: Shared hosting really isn't cut out for Magento, whatever the hosting provider might tell you - would really recommend you upgrade to VPS or better.

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't want to jump hosts, just set up multiple entries in crontab which do the same thing and are offset by the frequency you want the mail sent out.

But, really, this is an indication of a host which is not well-suited for Magento.

Comment: This might sound stupid but do you mean in my hostgator cpanel - cron jobs? or in my cron.php file?

Comment: I went to my hostgator cpanel and offset the time to */15+5 in the minute, it says "Cron field not formatted correctly."

Comment: If you want Magento cron executed every 5 minutes, then (given the 15 minute limitation) you can try `0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * *`. Or you can specify each entry individually if that doesn't work.

Comment: Cool! I did one job with */15 (every 0, 15, 30 and 45). Made a second one with 5,20,35,50 and a third one with 10,25,40 and 55. Everything works! so far so good, they have not removed it yet! Thanks for the tip

Answer (score -1):

I'ts possible to achieve that by modifying the Magento Core.
In the class Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template you can find the method `send(...)` in around line 371, and inside this method, find this line:

`$subject = $this->getProcessedTemplateSubject($variables);`

in my version its in line 392, there you can catch the content of the email in $text and the $subject, and send the email using PHP's mail() function.
I admit that this is not a clean way to do that, but this will fix the issue.